# Saving items after editing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language. The app which is called Vocabulary is written in C# and it loads/saves words from/into an XML document. Since I have recently switched from Windows to Linux, I am rewriting the app using Python.

Nevertheless, I am having troubles with saving a word after editing it.

Here is my C# method:

```
void Save()
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Word word = FindWord(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        word.WordOrPhrase = txt_Word.Text;
        word.Explanation = txt_Explanation.Text;
        word.Translation = txt_Translation.Text;
        word.Examples = txt_Examples.Text;
        listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text = txt_Word.Text;
        ReadOnlyON();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not selected any contacts!", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    SaveAll();
    WordCount();
    Sync();
}
```

...and here is my Python function:

```
def save_item(self):

    if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:

        word = self.find_word(self.listBox.curselection())
        word.wordorphrase = self.get_word()
        word.explanation = self.get_explanation()
        word.translation = self.get_translation()
        word.example = self.get_example()

        self.listBox.curselection() = self.get_word()
        self.read_only_ON()

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'You have not selected any word!')

    self.save_all()
    self.word_count()
```

The app won't start because:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 232
    self.listBox.curselection() = self.get_word()
               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also, when I comment out that line, I am getting another error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 227, in save_item
    word.wordorphrase = self.get_word()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wordorphrase'
```

Can somebody help me? I don't know how to access:

`listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text`

Also, it might be of some help if you have a look at my entire code:

```
# Vocabulary.py
# GUI program to manage unknown words

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os


class Word:

    def __init__(self, wordorphrase = None, explanation = None, translation = None, example = None):
        self.wordorphrase = wordorphrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.example = example
        self.translation = translation

class Vocabulary(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.master.title('Vocabulary')
        self.create_widgets()
        self.words = []
        self.load_words()

    def on_closing(self):

        self.save_all()

        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.master.destroy()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(row = 10, sticky = W)

        self.search_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.search_frame,
                                     width = 3)
        self.comboBox.grid(row = 0, column = 14, sticky = W)
        self.comboBox['values'] = ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )

        self.btn_Add = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                              text = 'Add',
                              command = self.add_item)
        self.btn_Add.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Remove = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                 text = 'Remove',
                                 command = self.remove_item)

        self.btn_Remove.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Edit = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Edit',
                               command = self.edit_item)
        self.btn_Edit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Save = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Save',
                               command = self.save_item)
        self.btn_Save.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Refresh = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                  text = 'Refresh',
                                  command = self.refresh_all)
        self.btn_Refresh.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)

        self.lblSearch = Label(self.search_frame, text = 'SEARCH: ')
        self.lblSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Search = Text(self.search_frame,
                               height = 1,
                               width = 70)
        self.txt_Search.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.lblWordsOrPhrases = Label(self.master, text = 'WORDS/PHRASES:')
        self.lblWordsOrPhrases.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.lblWordOrPhrase = Label(self.master, text = 'Word or phrase:')
        self.lblWordOrPhrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                               selectmode='extended',
                               height = 34,
                               width = 38)
        self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)
        self.listBox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.selectedIndexChanged)

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase = Text(self.master,
                                     height = 1,
                                     width = 40)
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExplanation = Label(self.master, text = 'Explanation:')
        self.lblExplanation.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Explanation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Explanation.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblTranslation = Label(self.master, text = 'Translation:')
        self.lblTranslation.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Translation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Translation.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExamples = Label(self.master, text = 'Example(s):')
        self.lblExamples.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Example = Text(self.master,
                                height = 10,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_Example.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = S)

    def load_words(self):

        self.listBox.delete(0, END)
        self.words.clear()

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        if not os.path.exists(vocabulary):
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(vocabulary)):
                os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(vocabulary))
            doc = ET.Element('Words')
            tree = ET.ElementTree(doc)
            tree.write(vocabulary)
        else:
            tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for node in tree.findall('WordOrPhrase'):
            w = Word(node.find('Word').text, node.find('Explanation').text, node.find('Translation').text,
                     node.find('Examples').text)

            self.words.append(w)
            self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

    def save_all(self):

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for xNode in tree.getroot().findall('WordOrPhrase'):
            tree.getroot().remove(xNode)

        for w in self.words:
            xTop = ET.Element('WordOrPhrase')
            xWord = ET.Element('Word')
            xExplanation = ET.Element('Explanation')
            xTranslation = ET.Element('Translation')
            xExamples = ET.Element('Examples')

            xWord.text = w.wordorphrase
            xExplanation.text = w.explanation
            xTranslation.text = w.translation
            xExamples.text = w.example

            xTop.append(xWord)
            xTop.append(xExplanation)
            xTop.append(xTranslation)
            xTop.append(xExamples)

            tree.getroot().append(xTop)

        tree.write(vocabulary)

    def add_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you have no words selected!')

        elif self.txt_WordOrPhrase['state'] == 'disabled':
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you refresh fields first!')
        else:
            if len(self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please enter the word!')
            else:
                w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())
                if not any(x for x in self.words if x.wordorphrase == w.wordorphrase):
                    self.words.append(w)
                    self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'That word already exists in your vocabulary!')

                self.clear_all()
                self.sync()
                self.word_count()

        self.save_all()

    def remove_item(self):
        for index in reversed(self.listBox.curselection()):
            self.listBox.delete(index)
            del self.words[index]

    def edit_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            self.read_only_OFF()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Nothing is selected!')
            self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'disabled')
            self.read_only_ON()

        self.sync()


    def save_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:

            word = self.find_word(self.listBox.curselection())
            word.wordorphrase = self.get_word()
            word.explanation = self.get_explanation()
            word.translation = self.get_translation()
            word.example = self.get_example()

            #self.listBox.curselection() = self.get_word()
            self.read_only_ON()

        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'You have not selected any word!')

        self.save_all()
        self.word_count()

    def sync(self):
        pass

    def word_count(self):
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Explanation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Translation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Example.delete('1.0', END)

    def refresh_all(self):
        self.clear_all()
        self.read_only_OFF()
        self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.word_count()
        self.sync()

    def get_word(self):
        return self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_explanation(self):
        return self.txt_Explanation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_translation(self):
        return self.txt_Translation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_example(self):
        return self.txt_Example.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def find_word(self, word):
        for x in self.words:
            if x.wordorphrase == word:
                return x

    def selectedIndexChanged(self, event = None):

        self.read_only_OFF()

        selected = self.listBox.curselection()

        if len(selected) == 0:
            self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'disabled')
            self.refresh_all()

            return

        try:
            word = self.words[selected[0]]

            self.clear_all()

            self.txt_WordOrPhrase.insert(END, word.wordorphrase)
            self.txt_Explanation.insert(END, word.explanation)
            self.txt_Translation.insert(END, word.translation)
            self.txt_Example.insert(END, word.example)

            self.read_only_ON()
            self.btn_Edit.config(state = 'normal')

        except Exception:
            return

    def read_only_ON(self):

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Explanation.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Translation.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.txt_Example.config(state = 'disabled')

    def read_only_OFF(self):

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Explanation.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Translation.config(state = 'normal')
        self.txt_Example.config(state = 'normal')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    gui = Vocabulary(root)
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', gui.on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Showing a c# version of your previous code, does not make this question a c# question, so you do not need to tag that language

Comment: What do you think this code is supposed to do? `self.listBox.curselection() = self.get_word()`

Comment: This: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wordorphrase'` means that `word` is `None`.

Comment: "Please don't post your entire code. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"—copied from Bryan from your other question

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to set the text of the item to be equal to the content of text widget

Comment: @abccd Okay, thanks, won't make such mistakes in the future

Comment: A return value of a call to a method cannot be assigned to something else, I believe you can't do that in c# either. `self.listBox.curselection() = self.get_word()`, in this case, your assigning the return value of `self.get_word()` to the return value of `self.listBox.curselection()` which actually doesn't make sense...

Comment: Yeah, it's logical to me as well. I tried to find an equivalent of `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text`

Comment: For the first error, take off the first parentheses: it should be `self.listBox.curselection = self.get_word()`, so you are actually assigning to a variable instead of a function call.

Comment: Thanks. What about `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wordorphrase'`? It seems that with `word = self.find_word(self.listBox.curselection())` I don't assign anything to `word` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
def save_item(self):

    if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:

        word = self.find_word(self.listBox.get(ACTIVE))
        word.wordorphrase = self.get_word()
        word.explanation = self.get_explanation()
        word.translation = self.get_translation()
        word.example = self.get_example()

        word_index = self.listBox.curselection()[0]
        self.listBox.delete(word_index)
        self.listBox.insert(word_index, self.get_word())
        self.read_only_ON()

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'You have not selected any word!')

    self.save_all()
    self.word_count()
```